# What Just Happened?

Tags: riddle, knowledge, story

The wife was out, the father was in, the men drank gin, the cards were played, it was hand made, the house was still, he wrote his will, then turned over, he found clover, so the phone rang, he would hang, but the gun went off, he paid the bill, but made nil, another coughed, the man hadn’t won, an ace is one, the Judge was good, the queen once stood, the Holy Ten, no mustached men, the ruler was red, but the maker was dead.

What just happened here?

(This is an original riddle, hopefully makes up for my first one)

Comment: There's an awful lot of card references in there...

Comment: So do you know exactly what happened, then?

Comment: I'm afraid not - I only know my regional card games, so I'm not going to break my head over this one.

Comment: rot13(jvyq thrff, ohg vf vg eryngrq gb znsvn?)

Comment: @Zobrothian, nevermind then. Mafia is a game that sometimes can start w/ players deciding their roles using cards.

Comment: @jazhang, sorry, I know what Mafia is. If you would like to put something about it as a solution, feel free to post an answer.

Answer (score 7):

Partial answer, but I think this is related to

> Poker

The wife was out,

> The wife folded

the father was in,

> The father did not fold

the cards were played, 
it was hand made,

> The cards were dealt

the house was still,

> Something to do with a full house

he wrote his will,

> He made a bet (?)

he found clover,

> Drew a club (or clubs)

so the phone rang,

> Someone called the bet

he would hang, 
but the gun went off,

> He would have checked, but someone raised. Not sure how to related the gun to the raise
>  Or, the person who called the bet instead decided to raise.

he paid the bill,

> He called the raise

but made nil,

> Didn't get what he wanted on the next card

an ace is one,
the Judge was good,
the queen once stood,
the Holy Ten,
no mustached men,
the ruler was red,

> His hand (not texas hold 'em?) was an ace, king, queen and 10. No jack (mustached man) so he missed the straight. The king was red, not a club, so he didn't land a flush either

but the maker was dead.

> He lost

Comment: you are VERY close. You missed the exact cards, which are rather important. If you knew the exact cards, you could also tell exactly what type of hand he was building, as well as the suit of each card. You also got the type of poker wrong, and "The gun went off" actually alludes to the player's position that raised.

Comment: When you say I got the type wrong, do you mean that it actually *is* rot13(grknf ubyq rz)?

Comment: Yup. It sure is. This should help you with the last couple bits